Copyright/Trademark for brand merchandise
I have noticed a lot of companies selling fake products of popular brands like Adidas and Nike by slightly modifying the logo or brand name. My school sells merchandise (t-shirts, hoodies, etc) with the school logo and name on them, and I thought it would be funny to slightly modify the logo and make my own t-shirts. I intend to misspell or rearrange the elements such that it isn't noticeable with a quick glance, but is certainly noticeable with a closer look. Would this be legal? Would my school care enough to get me in trouble? What if I start selling to friends?

I might also suggest you do a search here using the key word "parody".  I think you will find that there are a lot of questions very similar to this...


Would this be legal?

No. It would be a clear case of trademark infringement. There is no colorable parody or fair use type exception if as you state in the question: "I intend to misspell or rearrange the elements such that it isn't noticeable with a quick glance, but is certainly noticeable with a closer look."

Would my school care enough to get me in trouble?

The person who could sue you for trademark infringement would be the trademark owner. This site discusses what the law is, not how likely a particular trademark owner (who isn't even specified) is likely to litigate a particular trademark infringement case.
It might also violate school rules that the school could enforce. But that issue is entirely separate from the trademark/copyright issue.

What if I start selling to friends?

Then you would be violating trademark laws and exposing yourself to liability for willful trademark infringement, including possible punitive damages and attorneys' fees. In a worst case scenario, it could also be a federal crime. But it is unlikely that you would be prosecuted for federal criminal trademark infringement in that situation.

Is it even likely that a school would trademark their name or logo? You can't infringe a trademark that doesn't actually exist, can you?

@Barmar "Is it even likely that a school would trademark their name or logo?" Yes. It is very commonly done. Moreover, no formal filing is necessary for a common law trademark.

@Barmar looking up my school here, yes, they've trademarked the school name (wordmark), seal, and logo.
